# How can I use the "new" operator in a boost::xpressive semantic action?

Tags: c++, boost-xpressive

It seems that boost::xpressive doesn't provide a lazily evaluated version of the `new` operator, so this semantic action won't compile:

```
using namespace boost::xpressive ;
std::vector<int*> vec ;

// Match any integer and capture into s1.
// Then use a semantic action to push it onto vec.
sregex num = (s1= +digit)[ ref(vec)->*push_back( new as<int>(s1) ) ] ;
```

Is there a construct for using the new operator in semantic actions?  For example, boost::phoenix provides the [`new_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/object/new.html) function for lambdas.  Does xpressive provide something similar for semantic actions?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I've come up with so far.  This code defines a function that allows you to use the syntax `new_<T>::with(...)` as the semantic action equivalent to `new T(...)`. The function is modeled after the [lazy function example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.semantic_actions_and_user_defined_assertions.lazy_functions) in the [boost xpressive user guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html). (The snippet below only supports constructors with up to 2 parameters, but adding more is a matter of copy/paste.)

```
using namespace boost::xpressive ;

template <typename _ObjectType>
struct new_impl
{
    typedef _ObjectType* result_type;

    _ObjectType* operator()() const
    {
        return new _ObjectType() ;
    }

    template<typename _T0>
    _ObjectType* operator()(_T0 const &a0) const
    {
        return new _ObjectType( a0 ) ;
    }

    template<typename _T0, typename _T1>
    _ObjectType* operator()(_T0 const &a0, _T1 const &a1) const
    {
        return new _ObjectType( a0, a1 ) ;
    }
};

template <typename _ObjectType>
struct new_
{
    static const typename function<new_impl<_ObjectType> >::type with ;
};
template <typename _ObjectType>
const typename function<new_impl<_ObjectType> >::type new_<_ObjectType>::with = {{}};
```

And here it is in action:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int*> vec ;

    // Matches an integer, with a semantic action to push it onto vec
    sregex num = (s1= +digit)
                 [ ref(vec)->*push_back( new_<int>::with( as<int>(s1) ) ) ] ;

    // Space-delimited list of nums
    sregex num_list = num >> *(' ' >> num) ;

    std::string str = "8 9 10 11" ;
    if ( regex_match( str, num_list ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Found an int list: " ;
        BOOST_FOREACH( int* p, vec )
        {
            std::cout << *p << ' ' ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Didn't find an int list." ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Output:

```
Found an int list: 8 9 10 11
```

To improve the generality of the code above, it may be better to change the parameter types to use `boost::add_reference<>` and `boost::add_const<>`, but you get the idea.